Empty SOAP Responses - SharePoint Server 2019
I'm supporting a site that uses SOAP calls for passing in some data to create items and have a Test server we've been setting up but its giving List is not found errors with Lists that are on the site and empty results for things like the GetListsCollection when there are Lists there. The site loads fine and appears to have no errors. These were tested with a Farm admin account and a Site Collection Administrator account. Below is what was sent and what was returned, I have tried on multiple sites in the collection with the same results; no permissions errors and no errors that appear in the ULS log with the call. All services look fine in the Central Admin, I have tried running the Configuration Wizard, and tried restoring the site with no resolution so a bit stuck on what is causing the responses and any direction would be appreciated.
SENT
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"> soapenv:Header/ soapenv:Body soap:GetListCollection/ </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
RESPONSE
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Vary: Accept-Encoding Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-SharePointHealthScore: 0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 SPRequestGuid: 48491ea1-23d0-10c2-3c04-410e7f9ce9a6 request-id: 48491ea1-23d0-10c2-3c04-410e7f9ce9a6 X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN SPRequestDuration: 11 SPIisLatency: 0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.10396 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly Date: Fri, 12 Apr 2024 13:03:15 GMT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetListCollectionResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><GetListCollectionResult><Lists /></GetListCollectionResult></GetListCollectionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

